# Postback javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

when the user leaves the page I want to give message do you want to leave.
I am handling this in function pageUnload() event in javascript.But I don't want to
call this in the page postback I want to call when they navigate to different page

Answer (score 1):

Look into [`window.onbeforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onbeforeunload).

Note that Firefox 4 and up will not present the custom message to the user (but they do present a dialog asking if the user wants to leave). Safari, Chrome, and IE will.

Comment: Hi,Thx.but this too will fire when I submit my page.I want this to fire when the user moves to different page.But If i post back the page for some search it will fire that time too.I want to fire only if the user moves to different page not in postback.

Comment: You can add logic to disable it when they click certain elements.

Comment: This event will fire when you close window / tab or navigating to another page.